# How to loop through an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Given this:

```
var results = [
  {
        "Title": "Battle of Baekgang",
        "Space": ["South Korea"]
    },
    {
        "Title": "Victory Tests",
        "Space": ["United Kingdom"]
    },
    {
        "Title": "Everett massacre",
        "Space": ["United States"]
    },
    {
        "Title": "Bologna massacre",
        "Space": ["Italy"]
    },
    {
        "Title": "Milano massacre",
        "Space": ["Italy"]
    }
];
```

How would I loop it in order to say:

`If Space value` matching `myNation {do this}`?

Having set `var countries = ["Italy", United Kingdom", "South Korea"];`

I have `var regex = new RegExp(countries.join("|"), "i");`

And I know i could do `if(location.match(regex)) {`

But I need to first store `location` I guess as the name of `Space value`

Or any other/better way?

**UPDATE**

I have a `map` with polygons and each polygons have classes like:

```
<path class="italy france germany">
```

I could have `N`classes names for each country, the `json` I get would have one object called `Space` with one or more `countries` in it, so I'd need to check if any of the `json` countries, matches any class in any `polygons paths` on my `map` and if so, the path should get a `class active` added to it.

Comment: Do you mean if the `"Space"` value is matching one of the countries in `myNation`?

Comment: @abagshaw yes, just updated the question to make it clearer

Comment: @abagshaw updated again

Comment: https://codepen.io/DZuz14/pen/QMdNNe?editors=0012  Any help?

Comment: @DanielZuzevich i have a map with polygons and each polygon is a path, with a class as nation names, so if we match a country within the json, I should apply an active class to the path

Comment: BTW, there's no JSON in your question. It might have been once before you parsed it, but that's just an array of objects assigned to a variable.

Comment: just updated my question, wasn't clear, sorry

Comment: oh the downvote..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, this should work:

```
var results = [{
        "Title": "Battle of Baekgang",
        "Space": ["South Korea"]
    }, {
        "Title": "Victory Tests",
        "Space": ["United Kingdom"]
    }, {
        "Title": "Everett massacre",
        "Space": ["United States"]
    }, {
        "Title": "Bologna massacre",
        "Space": ["Italy"]
    }, {
        "Title": "Milano massacre",
        "Space": ["Italy"]
    }
];

var countries = ["Italy", "United Kingdom", "South Korea"];
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < results[i]["Space"].length; j++) {
        if(countries.includes(results[i]["Space"][j])) {
            var matchedCountry = results[i]["Space"][j];
            var currentTitle = results[i]["Title"];
            //Do other stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if we had a path on a map with a class matching the Space value, once it is true and we get to `Do this`, which would be the matched nation?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean. "Path on a map"?

Comment: i have a map with polygons and each polygon is a path, with a class as nation names, so if we match a country within the json, I should apply an `active` class to the path

Comment: I think you are asking two separate questions here. Find a solution here that answers this question and then maybe post another question separately for the second part (unless I'm misunderstanding this and the two problems are linked)

Comment: they are, in your answer which i like, how would I know what country names has been matched in roder to then be able to compare it with a class element i might have?

Comment: The matched country names are `results[i]["Space"]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151168/discussion-between-rob-m-and-abagshaw).

Comment: But my solution assumes there is only 1 country name in the array value for `"Space"`, (as your example only has one in each) - if there could be more than one then there needs to be a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

```
 results.filter(
   ({Space})=>countries.includes(Space[0])
 ).forEach(el=>console.log(el))
```

Simply filter, then loop over the filtered :/

---

Update: you may create just one Space Set:

```
var spaces = new Set(
  results.reduce((acc,el)=>[...acc,...el.Space])
 );
```

Then you can just go over your elems:

```
 var els = document.querySelectorAll("path");
 els.forEach(function(el){
  if(el.className.split(" ").some(clas=>spaces.has(clas))){
   //do sth
  }
 });
```

Comment: @kind user youre not the only one ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45439408/build-dynamic-table-whit-innerhtml/45439630#45439630

Comment: hey man, nice to see you again :) Thanks for this, what I am trying to do is basically i have a map with polygons and each polygon is a path, with a class as nation names, so if we match a country within the json, I should apply an active class to the path

Comment: @rob.m train station?

Comment: sort of... just a bit complex thing over here, lets put this way

Comment: @rob.m so results is one path? And wheres the html involved??

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would go:

```js
var results = [
  {
    "Title": "Battle of Baekgang",
    "Space": ["South Korea"]
  },
  {
    "Title": "Victory Tests",
    "Space": ["United Kingdom"]
  },
  {
    "Title": "Everett massacre",
    "Space": ["United States"]
  },
  {
    "Title": "Bologna massacre",
    "Space": ["Italy"]
  },
  {
    "Title": "Milano massacre",
    "Space": ["Italy"]
  }
];

var countries = ["Italy"];

for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  if(countries.includes(results[i]["Space"][0])) { // the [0] is because of Space being an Array
    console.log(results[i]["Title"]);
  }
}
```

Comment: i have a map with polygons and each polygon is a path, with a class as nation names, so if we match a country within the json, I should apply an active class to the path

Answer (score 0):

Below ES6 solution to find all entries that has `Space` within the `countries` array

```js
var countries = ["Italy", "United Kingdom", "South Korea"];
var regex = new RegExp(countries.join("|"), "i");
var results = [
  {
        "Title": "Battle of Baekgang",
        "Space": ["South Korea"]
    },
    {
        "Title": "Victory Tests",
        "Space": ["United Kingdom"]
    },
    {
        "Title": "Everett massacre",
        "Space": ["United States"]
    },
    {
        "Title": "Bologna massacre",
        "Space": ["Italy"]
    },
    {
        "Title": "Milano massacre",
        "Space": ["Italy"]
    }
];

let matches = results.reduce((acc,{Space}) => regex.test(...Space)?acc.concat(...Space):acc, []);

matches.forEach((i) => {
jQuery(`path.${i.toLowerCase()}`).addClass('active')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<path class="italy france germany">
</path>
<path class="should not be updated">
</path>
```

Comment: thanks man, i have a map with polygons and each polygon is a `path`, with a class as nation names, so if we `match` a country within the `json`, I should apply an `active` class to the `path`, this above would give me a json

Comment: The `active` class is the `Space` value ? and do you want the 1st match only or all of them ? if all of them, do you  want array back ?

Comment: what's the deal with ES6 I see it everywhere... From what I understand it's suppose to be an enhancement of JS syntax... Why isn't the community full embracing it though ?

Comment: @JasonKrs it is way beyond `embracing`. ES6 is the next major release of JavaScript!! You need to use google to get more information about this.